# semantic ui list/item right aligned buttons

Tags: html, semantic-ui

Hey im doing a page with [semantic ui](https://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html) Id like to make a list with middle aligned buttons. But they will always float after the other content [image]

```
<div class="ui divided list">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="ui tiny circular image">
        <img src="https://www.cutecatgifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/tail.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="middle aligned content">
        <div class="header">
          Name
        </div>
        <a class="meta" href="mailto:#">
          <i class="mail icon"></i> mail@mail.de
        </a>

        <div class="description">

          <i class="building outline icon"></i> 2-125 <br>
          <i class="fax icon"></i> 123-123-123
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="right floated"> <!-- this should be middle aligned -->
        <div class="ui middle aligned basic icon buttons">
          <a class="ui button" href="#"><i class="unhide icon"></i></a>
          <a class="ui button" href="#"><i class="write icon"></i></a>
          <a class="ui button" href="#"><i class="trash outline right icon"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hmm, using an `<i>` for an icon, and `<a>` for buttons is not semantic at all.

Comment: why are you using buttons inside divided list? can you align them in separate container?

Comment: so you mean its better to do a grid or something?

Comment: and an i tag is normal for icons